# Xcode exit to desktop suddenly

Tags: xcode

Hi I just bought a second hand macbook wanna learn coding . Upgraded it to the latest version for the macbook. ( macOS high sierra 10.13.4) Downloaded the latest Xcode 9. Was happily following some simple tutorial in YouTube when Xcode suddenly quit. And the system prompted me to “ignore” “reopen” “report”.

Can someone help me how do I solve this issue? Or Issit even normal :(

Comment: This would be better asked on https://superuser.com/

Comment: It seams crashed xCode. Does it crash every time you open?

Comment: Sometime there happened some exceptions and it cause crash...

Comment: It doesn’t occur frequently. Maybe once every two hour? Is there anyway I’m able to prevent it fully?